# What prepositions are appropriate with "Willkommen" and websites?

Tags: grammar, preposition

Which preposition is correct:

> Willkommen bei Myspace!!
>
> Willkommen auf meiner Website!

Comment: To me both seem correct for greeting someone visiting a web site. Note that "Welcome *as a new member of* (e.g.) myspace" works only with "bei".

Comment: Do you just use whatever preposition you'd normally use? "Wir sind im Klassenzimmer" -> "Willkommen in diesem Klassenzimmer"?

Comment: Meine Deutshlehrerin sagt immer ' Willkommen in der Deutschklasse!'

Comment: @thekeyofgb... yes!

Comment: @DerPolyglott33 Grammatically correct but sounds weird though.

Answer (score 5):

As for webpages, German uses the same preposition it uses for pages in a book and that is "auf.

"Bei" is used whenever it is something more personal and long lasting. Hence, when you're "bei" Myspace, you have an account, when you're "auf" Myspace you're just on the page.
That's why

> Willkommen bei meiner Webseite wouldn't really work.

There are many examples where either works.

> Das hab'ich auf/bei Wikipedia gelesen.

This is not fixed as of yet, so you might hear different versions.

Comment: Manchmal sagen die Deutschen ' in Facebook, in Youtube, in Myaspace'.

Comment: @DerPolyglott33 Ja, das ist was ich meine mit "not fixed"... es gibt noch kein richtig und kein falsch. Es gibt nur "oft" und selten... ich persönlich finde "in Facebook, youtube ..." falsch aber wenn andere das sagen, dann bitte

Answer (score 2):

If you explicitly refer to a site, **use `auf`**.

However, *Myspace, Facebook* and *Amazon.com* are not only (names of) websites. There are services, social networks, encyclopaedias, databases, retailers and much more out there and it depends on this which prepositions you can use (additionally to auf).

As an example take *Amazon.com*. You'd rather hear

> Das habe ich **bei** *Amazon* bestellt.

cause it's rather related to the retailer than to their site itself. It's the same with facebook. If you are not referring to the website itself (visiting it, describing certain features/functionality, etc), other prepositions than `auf` might be more commonly used.