# "Willkommen auf meinem Webauftritt" so korrekt?

Tags: style

Ich würde gerne *Webauftritt* anstatt *Website* oder *Homepage* verwenden, bin mir aber unsicher, ob man in diesem Fall auch *auf* sagt, oder eher *bei* (wobei das irgendwie komisch klingt).

Comment: Related: [What prepositions are appropriate with “Willkommen” and websites?](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9506/what-prepositions-are-appropriate-with-willkommen-and-websites)

Comment: "Webauftritt" klingt in diesem Zusammenhang schon ein bißchen komisch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Auch ich rate wie Emanuel zur Verwendung von "zu" im Zusammenhang mit "Webauftritt". Nicht wegen der Google-Ergebnisse – offenbar sind diese mittlerweile von User zu User verschieden. Der Grund ist, dass die virtuellen Vorgänge zwischen Client und Server in für uns leicht verständliche Metaphern übersetzt worden sind, und es wäre sinnvoll, diese Vergleiche, die aus anderen Bereichen stammen, logisch weiterzuführen.

Wenn von einer "Seite" die Rede ist (Homepage, Webseite), ist es daher nur konsequent, "willkommen ***auf***" zu verwenden, weil wir auch von Dingen sprechen, die *auf* einer Seite (Text, Bilderbuch etc.) stehen. Man antwortet ja z.B. auch auf die Frage, bis wohin man ein Buch schon gelesen habe, mit "ich bin auf Seite XY".

Dasselbe gilt für "Website", was wörtlich "Standort/Stätte/Gelände/Schauplatz im Netz" bedeutet. Von "Standort" vielleicht abgesehen, wofür man eher *an* verwenden würde, ist für eine Einladung an diese virtuellen Örtlichkeiten "unter freiem Himmel" die Präposition ***auf*** die passendste. Man könnte ja z.B. auch sagen: "Willkommen *auf* dem Schauplatz meines Auftritts im Netz".

Der "Auftritt" suggeriert, im Gegensatz zu einem Ort, ein Geschehen, und man wird ***zu*** etwas eingeladen, das geschehen wird: beispielsweise *zu* einer Geburtstagsparty, *zu* einem Abendessen, *zum* Auftritt einer Artistentruppe. Daher ist es nur logisch, *zu* einem Webauftritt einzuladen und die Besucher *zu* einem Webauftritt willkommen zu heißen. Der Vergleich sollte dann allerdings auch dahingehend halten, dass dieser "Webauftritt" tatsächlich die Persönlichkeit des Auftretenden spüren und erleben lässt und nicht stattdessen die Besucher mit ein paar leicht verwechselbaren Standard-Inhalten abspeist.

Für Web- bzw. Social Media-Strukturen, die einen geschlossenen Raum als Metapher haben, z.B.  für einen Chatroom, wird man vorzugsweise "willkommen ***in***" verwenden. Wenn sich eine eher geschlossene Usergruppe zu einem speziellen Vorhaben versammelt, könnte man ***bei*** verwenden, z.B. "Willkommen *bei* unserem Online-Kurs", aber *in* und *zu* sind genauso möglich.

Generell sollte man also meiner Meinung nach immer überlegen, welche Metapher verwendet wird, und die Formulierung dem jeweiligen Detail dieser Metapher anpassen.

Answer (score 1):

Am gängigsten ist "zu", aber die anderen beiden werden auch verwendet:

> Willkommen zu [ ] Webauftritt...   2.150.000  Treffer [bei Google](https://www.google.de/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1DVCJ_enDE430DE443&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22willkommen%20zu%20*%20webauftritt%22)
>   Willkommen bei [  ] Webauftritt...   295.000 hits [bei Google](https://www.google.de/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1DVCJ_enDE430DE443&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22willkommen%20bei%20*%20webauftritt%22)
>   Willkommen auf [  ] Webauftritt...   319.000 Treffer [bei Google](https://www.google.de/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1DVCJ_enDE430DE443&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22willkommen%20auf%20*%20webauftritt%22)

Comment: Persönlich finde ich ja "zu" dennoch am unschönsten, während "auf" mir am besten gefällt. "Webauftritt" sehe ich als Synonym zu "Webseite" und dort würde ich auch schon zu "auf" greifen. Interessant ist, dass bei der entsprechenden Google mit "webs(e)ite" keine klare Tendenz mehr zugunsten "zu" vorliegt.