# Logic consistency of prepositions between "Willkommen bei uns zu Hause" and "Willkommen bei Twitter"

Tags: preposition

I'm struggling with prepositions. What's the meaning of *bei uns* in this sentence?

> Willkommen bei uns zu Hause.

Or another example:

> Willkommen bei Twitter.

Why is it not like "Willkommen zu Twitter"?

Comment: Why should it be? Just because it's "to" in English it doesn't have to be the same in another language. Prepositions don't always translate directly and one of the big challenges is to just learn which one to use for which context. It's a journey that never ends.

Comment: Of course it doesnt have to be.But i try to integrate learning with my logic thats why i asked.İts context but i still dont understand why we dont say ''Wilkommen zu'' it doesnt have the meaning of ''welcome to''

Comment: Well the thing is that there isn't really an answer to the question "Why don't you say it this way"... it's simply because German doesn't. Like... why does English say "welcome to" and not "welcome by"? It's just how it is, is all.

Answer (score 6):

The confusion apparently arises from the fact that, as in the first sentence (*Willkommen bei uns zu Hause*) you also expect the appearence of *zu* in *Willkommen bei Twitter*, because you connect the *zu* with the English *to*. Well, that is erroneous: **Bei** is the preposition there that plays the role of *to*, whereas *zu Hause* is just, as a whole, *home.* And *uns* only determines whose home.

That said, *bei* is not the only preposition that can be used with *willkommen*. See this [question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9506/what-prepositions-are-appropriate-with-willkommen-and-websites) for a longer discussion.

Comment: Thanks for answer but im a bit confused and look straight and cant get the meaning i think,sorry but if ''uns'' determines whose home why it shouldnt be like ''Wilkommen bei unserem Hause'' why we say ''uns'' and use ''zu''

Comment: It's more we could say here. All of the follwing are possible: *Willkommen **bei** den Scht'is - Willkommen **in** Stuttgart - Willkommen **auf** unserer Internetseite - Willkommen **zu** unserem Kurs* - and probably more.

Comment: Thank you @Takkat i try to learn German by myself and dont have a friend know German thats why im asking this kind of questions